# Pfsense DNS Resolver not working for internal VM

Tags: dns, pfsense, plesk

I got Pfsense and 2 VM behind NAT. The 2 VM host Plesk with 1 domain (domain1.com on VM1 and domain2.com on VM2). When I go to domain1.com or domain2.com from external computer, no problem. But if I do ping or curl domain2.com from VM1 or ping/curl domain1.com from VM1, I got "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: domain1.com". But from VM1 or VM2, not problem to ping/curl other domain (like google.com).

Pfsense DNS Resolver is activated. When I disabled it and enabled Dns Forwarder, no more problem. But is there a way to activated Pfsense DNS Resolver and doing internal dns request works ?